# Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I'm using below command to download video of size 450MB:

```
JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"  && export JVM_ARGS && ./jmeter.sh -n -t  .../jmx_Tests.jmx -l jtlfilename.jtl
```

`jmeter.bat` file config is: `set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m`

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.DirectAccessByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(DirectAccessByteArrayOutputStream.java:43) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.toByteArray(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1872) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.readResponse(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1852)
```

But I'm getting an out of memory exception after 16 files downloaded. Then I changed to `-Xmx5120m`, still it is throwing same exception.

```
system details: 8 GB RAM
threads:50
```

Comment: Welcome Geetha. In order for us to help you, we will need some more information about your problem. It would help us if you could provide us with your `jmx_Tests.jmx` and if possible with a reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you, issue got fixed with Save Response as MD5 hash property.